# Infinite while loop - char to close not working C++

Tags: c++

The line:

```
cin >> cRestart;
```

is capturing the char, but the while loop is not terminating.  I need the code to move on.  Can you help please?
(The while loop looks for y, Y, n and N in case you can't see it all.)

```
    bool startInputValidation()
    {
        char cRestart = 'b';            //set initial value at b to run while loop

        conRGB(COLOUR_WHITE);           //text colour white

        conXY(0, 19);                   //cursor position in console
        drawLine();                     //draws a horizontal line across screen
        conXY(0, 23);
        drawLine();

        while (cRestart != 'y' || cRestart != 'Y' || cRestart != 'n' || cRestart != 'N')    //check for correct input (Y/N)
        {
            conXY(21, 21);
            for(int iCount = 0; iCount < 139; iCount++)                                     //blank lines
            {
               cout << " ";
            }
            conXY(21, 21);
            cout << "ARE YOU SURE YOU WISH TO CONTINUE Y/N?   ";                                    //ask question
            cin >> cRestart;                                                                //get input from user
        }

        if (cRestart == 'y' || cRestart == 'Y')                                             //if yes return true
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that `cRestart` will always be unequal to at least *three* of those characters at any one time.  You currently loop while it's unequal to at least one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Sigh, another programmer who has forgotten deMorgan's Law. it should be:

```
    while (cRestart != 'y' && cRestart != 'Y' && cRestart != 'n' && cRestart != 'N')    //check for correct input (Y/N)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It's very late and I'm very new to programming.  I will be searching deMorgan's Law tomorrow morning.

Comment: Cliff notes version: `!(A || B) == (!A && !B)`, and `!(A && B) == (!A || !B)`.

Answer (score 0):

This control structure

```
    char cRestart = 'b';            //set initial value at b to run while loop
    // ...

    while (cRestart != 'y' || cRestart != 'Y' || cRestart != 'n' || cRestart != 'N')    //check for correct input (Y/N)
    {
        conXY(21, 21);
        for(int iCount = 0; iCount < 139; iCount++)                                     //blank lines
        {
           cout << " ";
        }
        conXY(21, 21);
        cout << "ARE YOU SURE YOU WISH TO CONTINUE Y/N?   ";                                    //ask question
        cin >> cRestart;                                                                //get input from user
    }
```

1) is invalid ( it has invalid condition in the while loop
2) looks badly ( its better to use another control structure)

I would write the function the following way

```
bool startInputValidation()
{
    char cRestart;                  //set initial value at b to run while loop

    conRGB(COLOUR_WHITE);           //text colour white

    conXY(0, 19);                   //cursor position in console
    drawLine();                     //draws a horizontal line across screen
    conXY(0, 23);
    drawLine();


    do
    {
        conXY(21, 21);
        for ( int iCount = 0; iCount < 139; iCount++ )
        {
           cout << ' ';
        }

        conXY(21, 21);
        cout << "ARE YOU SURE YOU WISH TO CONTINUE Y/N?   ";

        cin >> cRestart;
        cRestart = toupper( cRestart );
    } while ( cRestart != 'N' && cRestart != 'Y' )

    return cRestart == 'Y';
}
```